# Error converting using SQL server 2012 conversion wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bids

I am using SQL Servers Integration Services Project Conversion Wizard and keep running into the following error:

> "An error occured while retrieving the value of property
>   "CertificateContext". The error code is 0x800200009.

I did a google search and nothing turns up concerning a conversion. The original **dtx** was written in **BIDS 9** (SQL server 2008 R2).

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try another copy of Project , that file may be corrupted 
or
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\1033\XML directory was corrupt and it was causing the problem.